# bookshelf.js - nested statement in where condition

Tags: knex.js, bookshelf.js

How can I write the below query in bookshelf.js?

```
select * from Table where (b=2 or b=3) and c = 4;
```

I am mainly concerned about the nested part (b=2 or b=3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since bookshelf is built on **knex**, I was searching for this in **knex.js** documentation.

Reference Link: https://knexjs.org/#Builder-where

```
knex('Table').where(function(){
  this.where('b', 2).orWhere('b', 3)
}).andWhere({'c': 4})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BookShelfTabelModel.where((qb) => {
        qb.where((qb1) => {
          qb1
            .where({
              b: 2,
            })
            .orWhere({
              b: 3,
            });strong text
        });
        qb.andWhere({ c: 4 });
      }).fetchAll()
```

**Note**

- This will generate query like following 
  select * from table where ((b = 2 or (b = 3)) and c = 4)